# Access the `b` parametr in the SVC object of scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, documentation

According to [scikit learn's mathematical model of the SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#mathematical-formulation) there is a parameter `b` (constant value of the model):

[image]

Yet in the [SVC class documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) I don't see how can one access its value.

Is there a way to access it? Is it really used?
I wonder if I need to manually add a column of `1` to the data or the model has it built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b is not a parameter, it is a part of a solution. The model solves for w and b to find a separating hyperplane. I guess you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Is there a way to access it? How can we be sure of that?

Comment: Check intercept_  parameter